# Retrofit dice que el body esta vacio @POST

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Tengo un servicio web con postman funciona mas que bien y me arroja este resultado:

```
{
"apellido": "Ortiz",
"tel": 7878,
"usuario": "DioShaw",
"nombre": "Yisus",
"idUser": 1,
"pswd": 123,
"puntos": 1250
 }
```

pero en el android studio esto: 
parece que acortara mi url quitando APistrping/v1 y la manda directo con 192.168.0.1/Login

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y Este otro error aplicando el metodo try catch

```
  E/response-success: >>  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke 
 virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.gson.JsonObject.toString()' on 
 a null object reference
```

Este es mi servicio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi clase como principal en el android studio

```
 public void vamoaello(){
        //creating the json object to send
        JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
        jsonObject.addProperty("usuario","dios");

        // Using the Retrofit
        IRetrofit jsonPostService = 
     ServiceGenerator.createService(IRetrofit.class, 
      "http://192.168.0.3:8080/APIspring/v1/");
        Call<JsonObject> call = jsonPostService.postRawJSON(jsonObject);

        Log.d(">>>> 82", jsonObject.toString());
        call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, 
                  Response<JsonObject> response) {


                Log.e(">>> a", "er"+response.raw());
                Log.e(">>> e", "er"+response.raw().body());
                Log.e(">>> e", "er"+response.raw());
               Log.e(">>> e", "er"+response.toString());
              //  Log.e(">>> e", "er"+response.body().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(">>> e", t.toString());
            }
        });
    }
  }
```

mi interfaz

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, tienes un servicio corriendo localmente? "192.168.0.1/Login". Si ese no es el caso creo que estas apuntando a un endpoint que no es el correcto.

Comment: No no tengo ese servicio pero ya pude solucionar el problema, primero en mi clase interface IRetrofit en @POST("/Login")  esta mal es sin "/"